# MySQL Case Statement (if else if equivalent)

Tags: mysql, position, case

I'm attempting to re-order a list based on their positions upon updating the position of one item via the submission of a drop-down box (which has a name assigned to the PHP variable $position). Here's an example, with positions represented by their order in the list:

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4
5. Item5

I'm using the following MySQL query:

```
UPDATE subjects SET 
position = position + 1 
WHERE position <= position AND position >= {$position};
```

If I was to move Item5 to position 2 this query would push everything from position 2 to 4 downwards by one position, resulting in:

1. Item1
2. Item5 *<<< moved up*
3. Item2
4. Item3
5. Item4

However, If I wish to do the opposite and move an item downwards, the position would need to become one less (position = position - 1), and the <= and >= signs would swap. Therefore I'm wondering how I would do this in a case argument (an equivalent to if{} else if{})

Answer (score 4):

If you need the if else you can use the MySQL `case` statement ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)).  It basically works as follows:

```
CASE case_value
  WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
  [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
  [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

And you can nest them as required.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try it

```
update subjects set position=(CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN 
        position+1
    WHEN search_condition THEN 
    postion-1
    else
       postion
END CASE) WHERE position <= position AND position >= {$position} AND menu_type = '{$menu_type}'";
```

Comment: What is meant by "search_condition"? Thanks

Comment: No need to be sarcastic. It hasn't been made entirely clear what format it should be in; I'm assuming it will be: "position < $position" and then "position > $position"

Comment: The following query gives an error:

   $query = "UPDATE subjects SET  
       position = (CASE WHEN position < {$position} THEN position+1 WHEN position > {$position} THEN position-1 else position END CASE) 
       WHERE position <= position AND position >= {$position} AND menu_type = '{$menu_type}'";